# git cannot push to master branch

Tags: git, bash, github

1. git repostory in github contains below branches
   (master,'abc' )
2. clone git repo abc branch to local machine
3. go inside to the repo folder using git bash
4. create git branch called `bbb`
5. checkout to the branch `bbb`
6. add files to repo folder
7. commit the changes
8. push changes to the remote repo `abc` branch
   used this command:

   ```
   git push origin bbb:abc
   ```

   It works fine.
9. then going to push changes to the remote repo master branch
   used this command:

   ```
   git push origin bbb:master
   ```

Then the below error message comes:

```
 ! [rejected]        bbb -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sw7x/testing4.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: Any chance somebody has pushed changes during your clone and your push?

Comment: If you want to push by force, try `push -f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As git itself said:

```
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

first `pull` (or even `fetch`) from master, do the required changes and finally `push`. If you're a mean person and do **NOT** care about other people changes, you can use `push -f` to force the push.

The reason you get this error is that your local version is different from the version resides in github repo and you should reconcile those two somehow to be able to `push` your code.

Comment: then why this works
push changes to the remote repo abc branch from local bbb branch

used this command

git push origin bbb:abc it works fine

Comment: maybe because you're the only one that work on branch abc

Comment: From what you describe the ABC branch is behind master both in your local repository and in github.

Comment: what is the meaning of ABC branch is behind master branch ?